# With vb.net, Is there a way to find all compressed files within a folder and its subfolders?

Tags: vb.net

I know how to find .zip files based on using the extension, but does anyone know of a way to find all compressed files without having to specify each type or extension?

Here's some code with pseudo logic at the end of it.

```
Dim zipFiles = New DirectoryInfo(tempFolder & "\extract") _
                          .GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories) _
                          .Where(Function(f) FILE IS COMPRESSED
```

So basically without having to specify every type of zipped/compressed extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This in simple words is not possible. Though you could do this for a few well-known compression algorithms and formats, it is important to understand that anyone could come up with a new compression technique that would use its own file structure to store compressed data. Also try to understand that an uncompressed file could technically contain exactly the same sequence of bytes that would be generated by a compression algorithm for some input. So generally speaking, the extension in most cases is the only way of deciding whether or not a particular file contains compressed data.

Therefore your best bet would be to Google for the list of known compression formats and the file extensions they use and use the `GetFiles()` method with that list.

Comment: Your answer makes sense, even though it isn't what I wanted to hear. haha... But it does make sense. Thank you.